# Unable to Create Storage pool on Azure VM 2016

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created 6 disks of 256GB each on 2 windows server 2016 VMs. I need to implement Active-Active SQL failover cluster on these 2 VMs using S2D.
I am getting error while creating storage pool for 3 disks , below is the error

```
Cluster resource 'Cluster Pool 1' of type 'Storage Pool' in clustered role xxxxxx failed. The error code was '0x16' ('The device does not recognize the command.').

Based on the failure policies for the resource and role, the cluster service may try to bring the resource online on this node or move the group to another node of the cluster and then restart it. Check the resource and group state using Failover Cluster Manager or the Get-ClusterResource Windows PowerShell cmdlet
[Problem start date and time]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is appearing because i tried to create storage pool again..basically, enable-s2dcluster has created the pool already for me..i didnt notice it and was trying to create the pool using Failove cluster manager

Answer (score 0):

S2D is new in Windows Server 2016. You can check [what to have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-create-failover-cluster#what-to-have) before you process with building your failover cluster. It's strongly to validate cluster first and then enable S2D following [Configure the Windows Failover Cluster with S2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-create-failover-cluster#step-2-configure-the-windows-failover-cluster-with-s2d).

Comment: I followed those links before creating S2D , so I am not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve an active-active solution, you should configure a host/VM per location. For Azure, S2D does not work between two locations. It requires RDMA support for the performance that cannot be configured in Azure. So, to get HA for SQL FCI to check StarWind vSAN free that can be configured between sites replicating/mirroring storage. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/installing-and-configuring-a-sql-server-failover-clustered-instance-on-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines
I see the following configuration: Storage Spaces provides disk redundancy configuring mirror or parity for each VM and StarWind distributes HA storage on top of underlying Storage Spaces.